# Awk: Combining columns from multiple files with calculations on data spanning several lines

Tags: bash, awk

How to combine selected columns from multiple files into a single file, and perform some calculations on adjacent line data ?

Here's an example : several data files from several devices each reporting data for several sensors for each month. So there's one file/device/month and I'd like to have one file/sensor.

Here are some sample data and expected output.

Example data file for `device0_202105.csv`:

```
Date;Time;Timestamp;PM2_5;AQI;PM10;CO2
2021/05/01;00:00:49;1619827249;21.0;70;29.0;413
2021/05/01;00:10:49;1619827849;20.0;68;37.0;409
2021/05/01;00:20:49;1619828449;21.0;70;39.0;412
2021/05/03;08:10:39;1620029439;33.0;95;43.0;430
2021/05/03;08:20:39;1620030039;33.0;95;50.0;427
2021/05/03;08:30:39;1620030639;35.0;99;38.0;429
2021/05/03;08:40:39;1620031239;33.0;95;46.0;431
2021/05/03;18:10:39;1620065439;12.0;50;18.0;425
2021/05/03;18:20:39;1620066039;12.0;50;18.0;426
```

Example data file for `device0_202106.csv`:

```
Date;Time;Timestamp;PM2_5;AQI;PM10;CO2
2021/06/01;08:19:16;1622535556;19.0;66;30.0;426
2021/06/01;08:29:16;1622536156;20.0;68;33.0;454
2021/06/01;08:39:16;1622536756;24.0;76;31.0;456
2021/06/01;20:49:16;1622580556;36.0;102;32.0;447
```

Example data file for `device1_202105.csv`:

```
Date;Time;Timestamp;PM2_5;AQI;PM10;CO2
2021/05/03;11:14:59;1620040499;19.0;66;20.0;438
2021/05/03;11:15:09;1620040509;19.0;66;20.0;486
2021/05/03;11:15:19;1620040519;18.0;63;18.0;485
```

I would like to create one file per type of sensor (e.g. CO2) for the whole available data period (here 202105 and 202106) that would look like this `data-co2.csv` using the above data:

```
Date;Time;Device 0;Device 1
2021/05/03;10:30;429.25;469.667
2021/06/01;10:30;475.333
```

The data for each device is reported in columns and **each data point is an average over a certain time interval**.
So one line reports the average value for a time interval of the original data.

I'm considering initially only 2 time intervals for each **weekday** only: a morning time interval from 8:00 to 13:00 (labeled 10:30) and an afternoon time interval from 13:00 to 18:00 (labeled 15:30).

I planned to run an `awk` script launched by a `bash` script that would loop over device and period files.
Here is the beginning of my scripts.
However, I'm having trouble writing to the output file (should I use the `-inplace` option ?).
I'm thinking about an easier route : write to a temp file and concatenate to the output file later.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
touch data-co2.csv
gawk -v device=0 -v sensor=18 -f read-data.awk device0_202105.csv data-co2.csv
```

```c
#!/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    FS  = "[;/:]";
    OFS = ";";
    day  = 1 ;
    sam = 0 ; nam = 0 ; spm = 0 ; npm = 0 ;
}
FNR==NR {
    if ( $1 ~ /20[0-9]{2}/ ) {
        if ( $3 != day ) {
            if ( nam != 0 ) a[date";10:30"] = sam / nam ;
            if ( npm != 0 ) a[date";15:30"] = spm / npm ;
            day = $3 ;
            sam = 0 ; nam = 0 ; spm = 0 ; npm = 0 ;
        }
        if ( strftime("%u", $7, 1) < 6) {
            if ( $4 >= 8 && $4 <= 12 ) {
                sam += $sensor ;
                ++nam ;
            }
            else if ( $4 >= 13 && $4 < 18 )  {
                spm += $sensor ;
                ++npm ;
            }
        }
        date = $1"/"$2"/"$3 ;
    }
    next ;
}
{
    if ( device == 0 ) {
       for ( i in a ) {
           print i, a[i] ;
       }
    }
    else {
       i = $1"/"$2"/"$3";10:30" ;
       j = $1"/"$2"/"$3";15:30" ;
       print $0, a[i] ;
       print $0, a[j] ;
    }
}
```

Please note that each device reports data at different times and that data may be missing due to device malfunction, network issue, etc.

**Edited** following the comments.

Comment: If you change your question to be about how to work on, say, 3 files of 4 rows and 5 columns each instead of 10 files of 10 rows of 15 columns then you can post complete but minimal sample input and expected output which would make it much easier for us to understand whatever it is you're trying to do and so more people would be willing/able to help you with it. See [ask].

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the contents of at least one more file and the output you are expecting. We need to be able to test our solutions and we can't do that with just a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#setting ":" as FS allows taking hours as separate field
BEGIN { FS="[:;]" ; OFS="\t" 
        #this gawk feature helps properly addressing the arrays in the end
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
}

#get device ID from filename on every new file
#get device IDs in array
FNR==1 {devID=FILENAME ; sub(/_.*/,"",devID) ; devs[devID]=devID }

#select time ranges, sum up values in time ranges and count occurences
FNR>1 {
    if ($2 >= 8 && $2 <= 12) {
        vals[devID,$1,1030]=vals[devID,$1,1030]+$NF
        n[devID,$1,1030]++
        }
    else if ($2 >= 13 && $2 <= 17) {
        vals[devID,$1,1530]=vals[devID,$1,1530]+$NF
        n[devID,$1,1530]++
        }
#get dates in array
    dates[$1]=$1
}
    
END {
    #needed for value selection
    times[1030]="10:30"
    times[1530]="15:30"
    #print headers
    printf("date\ttime")
    for (dev in devs) {printf("\t"dev)}
    printf("\n")

    
    #print values
    for (date in dates) {
    #get day of week from system date command
        cmd="date -d"date" +%w"
        cmd | getline dow
    #do not use Sat+Sun
        if ( dow != 0 && dow != 6 ) {
            for (time in times) {
                printf(date"\t"times[time])
                for (dev in devs) {
                    if ( !vals[dev,date,time] ) { printf("\tN/A") }
                    else { printf("\t"vals[dev,date,time]/n[dev,date,time]) }
                }
                printf("\n")
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant, but it gets the job done. Note that the array traversal option form `gawk` is a necessity to ensure that the column headers for the devices match the values.

Example output form files called 1_04, 2_04, and 3_02 created from your sample input with a few dates added (May 1st and 2nd are weekend days and not selected, added more days to test "N/A") and a few numbers crumbled (to ensure matching number and device).

```
date    time    1   2   3
2021/05/03  10:30   832 N/A 832
2021/05/03  15:30   406 401 406
2021/05/04  10:30   809 809 1009
2021/05/04  15:30   N/A N/A N/A
2021/05/06  10:30   N/A 832 N/A
2021/05/06  15:30   N/A N/A N/A
```

As you can see, it will even show when whole days or time intervals do not give values for all devices. But the respective date must be in the log file.

Comment: Nice! This gives exactly the desired output. The N/A is very neat indeed. I wanted to avoid using large arrays for resources, but I believe it's difficult to go around that.

Comment: Well if RAM is a limiting factor, you could A) combine files for same devices only and write to a file on disk, then B) use `join` pairwaise. ... Or c & d) do it monthwise for all devices, then concatenate.

Comment: +1.  BTW, you can avoid running external program `date` by using awk's `strftime()` and `mktime()` functions.   e.g. `datespec = gensub(/\//," ","g",date) " 00 00 00"; dow = strftime("%u",mktime(datespec))`.   Note that `mktime()` requires space-separated "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" with an optional daylight saving flag,  and is assumed to be local time zone unless you use the utc flag.  gawk's `gensub()` function is used here to convert YYYY/MM/DD into that format. in other versions of awk, you could use `datespec=date " 00 00 00"; gsub(/\//," ",datespec)` instead.

Comment: I removed the call to the `date` command and added a test `(strftime("%u", $5, 1) < 6)` (taking advantage of the timestamp already in the data) before the time range selection in the main rule. This also save some computing resources. Also `OFS` seems to have no effect when using `printf`.